# Creating Arcade Expression that excludes empty field values

Tags: arcgis-online, expression, arcade

In ArcGIS Online, I have a point layer with attributes Provider1, Provider2, Provider3.....Provider13. The values are text consisting of people's names.

I would like to configure the popup to concatenate the Providers separated by a semi-colon. However, some points only have a value for Provider1. Other points only have a value for Provider1 and Provider2. Other points only have a value for Provider1, and Provider2, and Provider3... etc.

Currently I simply have:

```
Concatenate($feature.PROVIDER1, ';', $feature.PROVIDER2, ';', 
$feature.PROVIDER3,';', $feature.PROVIDER4,';',$feature.PROVIDER5)
```

But for points that have only Provider1, the popup shows:

> John J. Doe; ; ; ;

Is there a way to to have the expression "stop" trying to concatenate when it encounters an empty Provider value?

Comment: Yes is the short answer, you want to be studying the logic functions [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/logical_functions/). May be the `IIF` or `When` functions?

Answer (score 7):

You must test IsEmpty for each value. You may try this code using the Labeling Profile at the [Arcade Playground](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/playground/)

```js
//Array to hold values and an index
var i = 0;
var features = [];

//Add value to array if not empty
function addvalue(feat) {
    if (!IsEmpty(feat)) {
        features[i++] = feat;
    }
}

//Add your values
addvalue($feature.name1);
addvalue(Null);
addvalue($feature.name2);
addvalue("");
addvalue("text");

//Return a concatenated string
return Concatenate(features, ";")
```

This will return:

```js
value1;value2;text
```